# Game Theory Puzzle

Tags: game-theory, dice

You are competing in a game with 2 other players, with a 21-faces dice (labeled 1-21). All three of you gets to choose a number and then roll the dice. Whoever chose the number closest to the outcome wins. What is your strategy if you three cannot communicate with others?
another twist: what if all three of you can communicated?

Comment: What happens in the event of a tie?

Comment: No one will win if they tie...

Comment: Do you all choose at the same time, or one at a time?

Comment: You choose a number before the game...so the order does not matter cause you don't know others choices....

Comment: Is the die rolled once only, or once for each player?

Comment: Sure the dice is rolled only once for all the players, but it will go many rounds as I want the expected value

Comment: Many rounds? You say nothing about that in your question.

Comment: Hey, this is a expected value question......It's kind of a common sense lol...

Comment: There is no mention of expected value in your question either... Anyway, the game with more than one period (finite or infinite period) is a different game to the one-shot game.

Comment: eh....yep, this question is a little bit unclear

Answer (score 0):

*I'll have another go:*

Since there is complete symmetry w.r.t. the players and no hidden information, no strategy can give any one player the advantage.

If the players are allowed to communicate, it is difficult to say anything mathematically, since the complexity then greatens considerably (and human psychology and/or interpretations of what a rational player is comes into play).

Comment: To whoever downvoted, would you mind explaining why? Please do point out if I've made any mistake(s).